# Can not reset admin password using reset password form

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter and PHP. I was developing a project where I have an admin role to change all features. I was trying to reset my admin password by using the reset password form. But when I am trying to submit the form.

When I am submitting the form it's showing an error message which I am tried to solve but I need some assistance to fix it. The error message is:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>   Message: Call to undefined method Mailer::Tpl_PwdResetLink()
>   Filename: /home1/jobyouxy/public_html/application/controllers/admin/Auth.php
>   Line Number: 103
>
> Backtrace:
>   File: /home1/jobyouxy/public_html/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once"
>
> Filename: /home1/jobyouxy/public_html/application/controllers/admin/Auth.php
>   Line Number: 103

[image]

> File: /home1/jobyouxy/public_html/index.php
>   Line: 315

[image]

See the screenshots of my code of this file location showing on the error message.

Comment: `$this->mailer->Tpl_PwdResetLink()`... is `mailer` a model, a controller, a method within the same controller or what?

Comment: Also, please do not (ever) post screenshots of your code as it makes it very uncomfortable for anyone wishing to help you to see/copy it (think that many, myself included) may be looking at this on a mobile device. always paste your code as code within your question

Comment: I think the mailer model has not Tpl_PwdResetLink() function. Please add model code here so we can check it.

Comment: I am trying to debug it also trying to find out why it's happening

Comment: If I comment on the line $this->mailer->Tpl_PwdResetLink() then email is sending but the email body is not sending with the link. is there any way to send an email body with reset password link?